# RewriteRule not working

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to add a rewrite rule in my `httpd.conf` file but it's not working.

Here's the relevant section:

```
RewriteRule ^/taxonomy/term/([0-9]+)$ http://www.example.com/taxonomy/term/$1 [R=301, L]
```

Currently, my site name is www.domain.com and I am trying to redirect all the URLs starting with `taxonomy/term/{integer}` to my new domain www.example.com through an `httpd.conf` `RewriteRule`.

Comment: why dont you try with .htaccess

Comment: i more point which i would like to add, once i add the above line in httpd.conf file i am unable to restart the httpd services.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apache must have complained about:

> RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

Remove the white space in your flags. Change this:

```
[R=301, L]
```

to:

```
[R=301,L]
```

Note: if you're using the rule inside a per-directory htaccess file, you need to omit the leading slash:

```
RewriteRule ^taxonomy/term/([0-9]+)$ http://www.example.com/taxonomy/term/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Are u aware of some online site wherein we can quickly check the same?

Comment: I'm not aware of any website that allows you to tamper with .htaccess files :) But [this website](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) might help.

Comment: Thanx Salman... But this site no were states the error.. as u have pointed out above "RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters"..

Comment: Hmmm, the website probably cannot tell if your htaccess or conf file is OK. The error I mentioned was logged in Apache logs; it is the first place you should look when you see the dreaded *500 Internal Server Error*.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the beginning slash:

```
 RewriteRule ^taxonomy/term/([0-9]+)$ http://www.example.com/taxonomy/term/$1 [R=301, L]
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your inputs. i have already tried that but not working :(

Comment: i was unable to restart the services after the above mentioned changes?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in httpd.conf (remove the space, don't remove the slash):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/taxonomy/term/([0-9]+)$ http://www.example.com/taxonomy/term/$1 [R=301,L]
```